# "Get {something} through to {somebody}" vs. "Get {something} across to {somebody}"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, expressions, phrasal-verbs

How do these expressions differ?
Does one of them sound more forceful to you?
For instance, in the following sentence, does using each one make any change in meaning:

> 1. What are you trying to get **across** to me?
> 2. What are you trying to get **through** to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. "Get {something} [across](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-across) to {somebody}"

means "Present {something} in a way that {somebody} can understand", or "Explain in a way that {somebody} shows they understand".  The phrasing assumes that the problem is a difference in language or assumptions.  For example, science teachers often have a hard time getting quantum mechanics concepts across to their students.

> 2. "Get {something} through to {somebody}"

means "Force {somebody} to accept that {something} is true", or "Convince."  The phrasing assumes that {somebody} is resisting the idea of {something}.  For example, football coaches sometimes need to get through to their players that academics are important -- and that if a student doesn't earn good grades, the student won't be allowed to play football.

Thus, "get {something} through to {somebody}" is more forceful.